# Show that a continuous function has a fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

Question: Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$ and let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$ continuous. Show: $f$ has a fixed point, that is, there is an $x \in [a,b]$ with $f(x)=x$.

I suppose this has to do with the basic definition of continuity. The definition I am using is that $f$ is continuous at $a$ if $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ exists and if $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$. I must not be understanding it, since I am not sure how to begin showing this... Should I be trying to show that $x$ is both greater than or equal to and less than or equal to $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ ?

Comment: I don't know what lim_{x \to x} f(x) is supposed to mean.  Try drawing some examples of f (say with a = 0, b = 1) to convince yourself that this is plausible, then think about the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Here is an interesting answer: https://www.quora.com/Which-of-the-numerous-fixed-point-theorems-would-be-optimal-for-proving-continuous-bounded-function-f-mathbb-R-to-mathbb-R-has-a-fixed-point-i-e-exists-y-in-mathbb-R-s-t-f-y-y-analysis-1-exam-1st-year/all_comments/Kabir-Belgikar?__filter__=all&__nsrc__=1&__sncid__=3907372066&__snid3__=6402861838&comment_id=124371656&comment_type=2

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Let $g(x) = f(x) - x$.  Then $g$ is continuous and $g(a) \geq 0$ while $g(b) \leq 0$.  By the Intermediate Value Theorem, $g$ has at least one zero on $[a, b]$.

Answer (score 20):

For a different approach then the ones above, let us take $a = 0$ and $b = 1$. So assume $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ has no fixed point. Then $[0,1] = \{x \in [0,1] : f(x) < x\} \cup \{x \in [0,1] : f(x) > x \}$. Now argue that this is not possible.

Answer (score 19):

Consider $g(x)=f(x)-x$.  $f(a)\ge a$ so $g(a)=f(a)-a\ge 0$.  $f(b)\le b$ so $g(b)=f(b)-b\le 0$.  By the Intermediate Value Theorem, since $g$ is continuous and $0\in[g(b),g(a)]$ there exists $c\in[a,b]$ such that $g(c)=f(c)-c=0$, so $f(c)=c$ for some $c\in[a,b]$.

Answer (score 11):

Consider $x-f(x)$ and use Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 4):

If $f(0) = 0$ we are done. If the former is not true then, since $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$, it must be that $f(0) > 0$. Applying the same reasoning we conclude that $f(1) = 1$ (and we are done) or $f(1) < 1$. Lets asume then that $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)<1$ .

Take $g: [0,1] \to [0,1]$  such that $g(x) = f(x) - x$. If $0$ belongs to $\text{Image($g$)} $ then we are done. If it does not, then $\text{Image($g$)} $ is contained in the union the following disjoint sets:
$(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$.

These two open sets disconect $\text{Image($g$)} $, a contradiction since $g$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is connected.

Answer (score 2):

You could argue on the contradiction by assuming your given function has a fixed point. By definition a function has a fixed point iff $f(x) = x$. If you substitute your function into the definition it would be clear you  get an impossible mathematical equality, thus you have proved by contradiction that your function does not have a fixed point.
Hope this helps. Try with $f(x) = 1+ e^x$, because as already stated it is one of the functions which has no fixed point.

Answer (score 1):

You could also nuke the mosquito: in particular, this is a special case of [Kakutani's fixed point theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakutani_fixed-point_theorem)

This works because:

- By the [closed graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem), the compactness of the codomain of $f : [a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$ is sufficient to deduce the closedness of its graph.
- Given $x \in [a,b]$, the element $f(x)$ can be identified with the corresponding singleton set $\{f(x)\}$, and every singleton set is non-empty and convex.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the property of continuous function on compact set. Take g(x) =|x - f(x)| on [a,b]. Clearly g is continuous so image of g must be compact, hence it will achieve it's minimum value. Can you show now that minimum will be zero ?

Comment: How to show the minimum will be zero?