# Avoiding rationals $\implies$ constant

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry

If $f:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, with $n>1$, is a continuous curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $f(p)=(x_1(p),x_2(p),...,x_n(p))$. Must the set of $p$ such that for some $i$, $x_i(p)$ is a rational number, be dense in $(0,1)$?

$f$ is non-constant on every open interval of $(0,1)$.

Comment: You can set $n=1$ because one $f$ has all the $x_i$ equal.

Comment: I want to know if its true for all f

Comment: @lbhezbgure Then it's trivially false. Let $f(x)=(\pi,\ldots,\pi)$.

Comment: How is a point a continuous curve?

Comment: @lbhezbgure It's the simplest example of one. But if you're picky, just let $f$ be constant on some interval in $(0,1)$.

Comment: I am very picky. And we need $n>1$. If f is constant its a point in R^n, not a curve, and not continuous.

Comment: @lbhezbgure A "continuous curve" is defined as a continuous mapping $\gamma:I\to X$ where $I\subset\R$ is an interval and $X$ a topological space. The constant curve satisfies this. It is trivially continuous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb R^n$ is such that it does not attain rational values on no coordinate for some non-trivial subinterval $I$ of $[0,1]$. This means that the restriction can be considered as a continuous map $f\colon I \to (\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)^n$. We will show bellow that such map must be constant.

So if you assume that your map $f$ is not constant on any subinterval of $[0,1]$, then the set of points having at least one rational coordinate must be dense.

---

The fact that such map is constant follows from the fact that $I$ is [connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space) and $(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)^n$ is [totally disconnected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space). Every continuous map from a connected space to a totally disconnected space is constant.

However, it would be good to add a self-contained proof for this special case, so that this answer is self-contained and readable for someone not familiar with connected and totally disconnected spaces. <s>I'll try to find whether we have something like that in another question at this site, if I don't find anything, I'll add a proof here.</s> I've tried to add a proof for this special case, but I don't think this proof can be followed without at least basic knowledge of general topology. (The proof bellow would work for any [totally separated space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_separated_space).)

Proof for this special case can be done very similarly as the proof for the theorem I mentioned above: Denote $Y=(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)^n$. Assume that $f\colon I\to Y$ is not constant. So you have at least two distinct points $a,b\in f[I]$. These two points differ at least in one coordinate $a_k$, $b_k$, which implies that they can be separated by a hyperplane $x_k=q$, where $q$ is some rational number between $a_k$ and $b_k$. This hyperplanes determines two open half-spaces. Their intersections with $Y$ give two disjoint open subsets $U$, $V$ of $Y$ such that $a\in U$, $b\in V$ and $U\cup V=Y$. Hence $f^{-1}[U]$ and $f^{-1}[V]$ are non-empty open disjoint subset of $I$ such that their union is $I$. This is not possible since $I$ is connected.

See [Continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112043/continuous-functions-from-mathbbr-to-mathbbq) and
[Continuity leads to constant function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141189/continuity-leads-to-constant-function-assignment-question) for other special cases of the above theorem.