# $f(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(\mathbb{Q}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ imply that $f$ is not continuous

Tags: general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No continuous function that switches $\mathbb{Q}$ and the irrationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55638/no-continuous-function-that-switches-mathbbq-and-the-irrationals)

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be function satisfying the two conditions: $f(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(\mathbb{Q}) \subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Then,

> Show that $f$ cannot be continuous.

I'm trying this problem for some time but can't make any useful progress. I will appreciate any help. Even some good hints will do. Regards.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hint: The conditions imply the range of $f$ is countable and that $f$ is non-constant.

Comment: Supercool hint. Got it. Thanks a thousand tons! :-)

Answer (score 5):

If $ f $ is continuous we have that $ f(\mathbb{R}) $ is an interval. Thus  $ f(\mathbb{R}) $ is uncountable. On the other hand, we have
\begin{equation}
  f(\mathbb{R})  \subset f(\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q})  \cup f(\mathbb{Q})   
\end{equation}
Thus $f(\mathbb{R})$ is countable as union finite of countables.
 Contradiction.

Comment: $f(\mathbb Q)$ is not contained in $\mathbb Q$, since $f(\mathbb Q) \subseteq \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$, but of course $f(\mathbb R)$ is countable.

Comment: Sorry, I writed fast and did this mistake. But I will correct.