# Continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $f(\mathbb Q)\subseteq \mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ and $f(\mathbb R-\mathbb Q)\subseteq \mathbb Q$?

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No continuous function that switches $\mathbb{Q}$ and the irrationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55638/no-continuous-function-that-switches-mathbbq-and-the-irrationals)

Is there a continuous function $f\colon\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that $f(\mathbb Q)\subseteq \mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ and $f(\mathbb R-\mathbb Q)\subseteq \mathbb Q$?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251683/f-mathbbr-setminus-mathbbq-subseteq-mathbbq-and-f-mathbbq-sub/251685) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55638/no-continuous-function-that-switches-mathbbq-and-the-irrationals) .

Comment: @nice question ali. +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINT: If such an $f$ exists, $$\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q=\bigcup_{q\in\Bbb Q}f^{-1}[\{q\}]$$ is the union of countably many closed sets. Now apply the Baire category theorem.

Comment: I just love it when Baire knocks at the door ...

Comment: @Hagen: Lions and tigers and Baires [oh my]. :-)

Comment: Hammer, nails, and all that...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ has empty interior , yet I don't got it how your hint solve the question

Comment: @HarryPotter: The Baire category theorem implies that at least one of the sets $f^{-1}[\{q\}]$ is dense in some interval. If $x$ is a rational in that interval, $f(x)=q$ by continuity, contradicting the hypothesis on $f$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott sorry for my ignorance, Theorem Baire I know says that countable union of closed empty interior has empty interior or equivalently, countable intersection of open dense set is dense set. what am I missing?

Comment: @HarryPotter: Apply the Baire category theorem to $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, not to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott How Apply Baire the a non complete topological space?

Comment: @kLEIN: The irrationals are completely metrizable, which is all that’s required by the BCT.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  How  metric, can  you giveme a description? Sorry of  my ignorance.

Comment: @Eduardo: First find a homeomorphism between the irrationals and $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$. This can be done in several ways; continued fraction expansions are one way, and Theorem 1.1 of [these notes](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9401202) is another. Then for $\sigma,\tau\in\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ define $d(\sigma,\tau)=2^{-n}$, where $n=\min\{k\in\Bbb N:\sigma(n)\ne\tau(n)\}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is clearly that this  topology generated by this metric  is equivalent to canonical topology of the $\mathbb{R}$??

Comment: I wonder how many of the downvoters understand that the answer **is** correct, albeit less elementary than was actually necessary.

Comment: @HarryPotter: Of course. This isn’t basic calculus (and I apologize to the OP for not noticing the `calculus` tag and giving a `general topology` answer, though it seems to have done no harm), but it is fairly basic topology.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank's for your time.

Answer (score 13):

**Hint:** Consider a continuous function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. Either $f$ is constant or $f(\mathbb R)$ is uncountable. (Can you show this? *Sub-hint*: intermediate value theorem.) If $f(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)$ is countable, what  about the countability/uncountability of the set $f(\mathbb R)$, using the fact that $f(\mathbb R)=f(\mathbb Q)\cup f(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)$?

Comment: Ah, a smaller hammer; nice.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott [Indeed](http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/5468342/2/stock-photo-5468342-hand-holding-small-hammer.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose by contradiction that such a function exists. Then it is non-constant.

Let $a<b$ be so that $f(a) \neq f(b)$. Then by the IVT $f([a,b])$ is a non-trivial interval. Let call this interval $[c,d]$.

Thus

$$f([ a,b] \cap \mathbb Q)= [c,d] \cap (\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q) \,.$$
This implies that $f$ takes a countable set onto an uncountable set, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

See, $f(\mathbb{Q})$ is a countable set, how $f(\mathbb{R-Q})\subset \mathbb{Q}$, then, $f(\mathbb{R-Q})$ is too a countable set, then $f(\mathbb{R})$ is also a countable set. See, a continuous function have a countable image if only if $f$ is a constant function, contradiction!