# Existence of a continuos function in $[0, 1]$

Tags: special-functions

Can exist a continuous function $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x)\in\mathbb{Q}$ if $x\in\mathbb{I\cap [0, 1]}$ and  $f(x)\in\mathbb{I}$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q\cap [0, 1]}$? Why yes? why not?

Comment: Are you thinking of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251683/f-mathbbr-setminus-mathbbq-subseteq-mathbbq-and-f-mathbbq-sub/251685)?

Comment: See [this excellent answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/55640/28900).

Comment: Minor variants of this question have been asked several times before, see the two questions linked above, or this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251683/f-mathbbr-setminus-mathbbq-subseteq-mathbbq-and-f-mathbbq-sub?lq=1 All of these should provide you with many ways to tackle the problem!

Answer (score 0):

HINT: I assume that $\Bbb I$ stands for the set of irrational numbers. (In my experience $\Bbb P$ is more common.) For each $q\in\Bbb Q$ let $F(q)=\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)=q\}$; then $\Bbb I\cap[0,1]=\bigcup_{q\in\Bbb Q}F(q)$. Apply the [Baire category theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) to conclude that there are $a,b\in\Bbb I\cap[0,1]$ and a $q\in\Bbb Q$ such that $a<b$ and $\Bbb I\cap[a,b]\subseteq F(q)$. Then use continuity to conclude that $f$ is constant on $[a,b]$ and so get a contradiction.