# continuous onto function from irrationals in [0,1] onto rationals in [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis

Give a continuous surjective function from the irrationals in $[0,1]$ onto the rationals in $[0,1]$. Can we at least prove the existence of such a function? I couldn't see a function off the top of my head. Here we assume $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q$ with its usual metric.

Comment: Look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/55638/8271)

Comment: @leo That's a different question entirely.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I'm not sure. This one is tagged as real- analysis not topology. I mean your answer is OK as far as we consider relative topolgies in your $I$ and $\Bbb Q\cap [0,1]$. As these details are not stated in the question,  I assumed the standard topology for $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I think the question should include mention to topology, because in the standard topology of $\Bbb R$ this not true.

Comment: We're looking for a function with domain $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, not $\mathbb{R}$! Of course the topology matters, but the obvious choice of topology on the domain is the subspace topology inherited from the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that since I answered the question and you commented, the OP has updated the question to clarify the topology. The usual metric topology on $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is the same as the usual subspace topology.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $I = [0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q}$, the set of irrationals in the unit interval.

Partition $I$ into countably many nonempty pieces, each given by the intersection of an open set in $[0,1]$ and $I$, such that $I = \cup_{k=0}^\infty I_k$. For example,

$I_0 = \left(\frac{1}{2},1\right) \cap I$,

$I_1 = \left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right)\cap I$,

and in general $I_k = \left(\frac{1}{2^{k+1}},\frac{1}{2^k}\right)\cap I$. Note that each $I_k$ is open in $I$.

Enumerate $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ (in any way you like): $\{q_0, q_1, q_2,\dots\}$.

For any $x\in I$, $x\in I_k$ for exactly one $k$. Define $f(x) = q_k$.

Note that $f$ is surjective, since each $I_k$ is nonempty.

We want to show that $f$ is continuous. Let $O\subseteq \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ be an open set. We can write $O = \bigcup_{q_k\in O} \{q_k\}$.

$$f^{-1}[O] = \bigcup_{q_k\in O}\,f^{-1}[\{q_k\}] = \bigcup_{q_k\in O} I_k.$$

This is a union of open sets in $I$, so it is open.

Note that we didn't actually use that $O$ was an open set: our function $f$ is continuous even if we give $\mathbb{Q}$ the discrete topology!

Comment: As written, you have a problem. All numbers of the form $2^{-k}$ for $k\geq1$ isn't in $I_i$ for any $i$, so $I \neq \cup_i I_i$.

Comment: That is not a problem since I contains only irrationals in [0,1].

Comment: D'oh. I'm so used to $I$ meaning an interval of real numbers that I fooled myself into thinking it actually was one.

Comment: very nice answer.

Comment: @AlexKruckman - just one question, why is $I_k$ open for all $k$?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine $I_k$ is the intersection of an open interval with $I$, so it is open in the subspace topology on $I$.

Comment: So, $I_k$ is not open in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine Of course not: Every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ contains a rational number, and $I_k$ does not contain any rational numbers, since it is a subset of $I$. But whether $I_k$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ is irrelevant, since the domain of the function is $I$, not $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ohh alright, that makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The function $x\mapsto\left\lfloor\frac1x\right\rfloor$ maps the irrationals in $[0,1]$ continuously onto the countable discrete space $\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$, which can be mapped continuously onto any countable (nonempty) topological space, such as the space $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$.