# Existence of Continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a continuous function $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ which takes irrational values at rational points and rational values at irrational points?

Comment: No. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55638/no-continuous-function-switches-mathbbq-and-the-irrationals).

Answer (score 0):

By Baire category theorem, we can assume that such a function takes a constant rational value on a dense (comeager) subset of some interval. But then it is constant there.