# Can a continuous function with this property exist?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Can a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the following property exist: if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $f(x) \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, and if $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, then $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$?

**My attempt:** I don't see any problem with this function. I wanted to check if it is consistent with the intermediate value theorem. Let $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ and suppose that $x_1 < x_2$. Then $f(x_1) = y_1 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x_2) = y_2 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Intermediate value theorem says that for every $y$ satisfying $y_1 < y < y_2$ there exists an $x$ satisfying $x_1 < x < x_2$ such that $f(x) = y$. So I took a $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ satisfying $y_1 < y < y_2$ (I can do this since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$). Then, since $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is also dense in $\mathbb{R}$, there certainly exists an $x$ with the property that $x_1 < x < x_2$ and $f(x) = y$.

Or is there maybe something else wrong with this function that I don't see?

Comment: Such a function would take only countably many values. On the other hand, a non-constant continuous function must take uncountably many values.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55638/no-continuous-function-switches-mathbbq-and-the-irrationals).

Comment: I've made a small edit to your question; you mean to say the intermediate value theorem, not the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I will base my answer on Mr. David's Mitra's comment, for it might be the case that someone may not understand his comment fully.

Suppose that $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a function such that
$$\begin{align}
f(x)\in\Bbb Q &\quad\text{for all}\quad x\in\Bbb Q^c \\
f(x)\in\Bbb Q^c &\quad\text{for all}\quad x\in\Bbb Q.
\end{align}$$

It can be shown that $\mathcal R(f)$, the range of $f$, is a countable set. Indeed, 
$$
\mathcal R(f)=\mathcal R(f|_{\Bbb Q})\cup\mathcal R(f|_{\Bbb Q^c})\ .
$$
Since $\mathcal R(f|_{\Bbb Q})$ is the image of countable set, it is countable. $\mathcal R(f|_{\Bbb Q^c})$ is countable by the assumption that $\mathcal R(f|_{\Bbb Q^c})\subseteq\Bbb Q$. Thus $\mathcal R(f)$ is the union of countable sets so it is countable.

> However, every **continuous** function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is either a constant or its image, i.e. $\mathcal R(f)$, is uncountable!

To see this, we suppose that $f$ is not a constant function (it is obvious from the conditions on $f$ that $f$ cannot be a constant function) i.e. there exist $x,y\in\Bbb R$ such that $f(x)\ne f(y)$. Denote
$$
a=\min\{ f(x),f(y)\}, \\
b=\max\{ f(x),f(y)\}.
$$

By the Intermediate Value Theorem, for any $c\in(a,b)$ there is a $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$ such that $f(\xi)=c$. This shows that
$$
[a,b]\subset \mathcal R(f),
$$
contradicting the fact that $\mathcal R(f)$ is countable.

**Conclusion:** Such a function $f$ does not exist.

Comment: I followed your argument, but I don't understand your last step. How does $[a, b] \subset R(f)$ contradict the fact that $R(f)$ is countable? Because $[a,b]$ is uncountable and so it cannot be a subset of a countable set?

Comment: @Kamil Exactly! Every subset of a countable set must be countable (possibly finite).

Comment: @Kamil If there's anything else you want to ask, please feel free!