# Prove that $f$ has a fixed point .

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

For $f:[a,b]\rightarrow [a,b]$ is a continuous . Prove that $f$ has a fixed point . Is that true if we change $[a,b]$ by $[a,b)$ or $(a,b)$.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No it isn't. I find this problem in a book.

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13582/show-that-a-continuous-function-has-a-fixed-point

Comment: A possible counterexample for open interval: $f(x)=x^2$ as a function from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1)$. Or $f(x)=x^2/2$ if you want $(0,1]$.

Answer (score 5):

**Another idea without using Intermediate Value Theorem:**

**Proof:** Firstly, let us pick any point from $[a,b]$, say $x_0$. Assume we have defined $x_n$, let $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. Thus we abtain a sequence $\{x_n: n\in \Bbb N^+\}$ from $[a,b]$. Since $[a,b]$ is compact, then for any infinite subset of $[a,b]$ there exists an limit point in $[a,b]$, say $x$.

Then we can claim that $f(x)=x$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(x)=f(\lim x_n)=\lim f(x_n)=\lim x_{n+1}=x$. This complete the proof.

---

The interval $[a,b)$ or $(a,b)$ is not enough, Since $x$ maybe fell on the point $b$, which is no longer in the origin interval.

---

**Added: The answer seems right. However it is not right, just as  Landscape points; he gives us a counterexample in the comments. Many times if the answer is wrong, I will delete it immediately. However this is a special case. From it, I learn some lessons. Something cannot be of course. So I hope to keep it as long as I can.**

Comment: Your argument does not work, because $x_n$ may not converge, despite that is has convergent subsequence.

Comment: @Landscape: Yes. $x_n$ may not converge, however there must exists an accumulation of the sequence.

Comment: Then how do you define $x$ and how do you conclude $f(x)=x$?

Comment: @Landscape:  Pick any one accumulation point with corresponding subsequence $\{y_n\}$ of $\{x_n\}$.

Comment: Please consider my comments seriously. If you define $x$ is this way,  $f(x)=x$ does not hold in general.

Comment: @Landscape: We can replace $\{x_n\}$ with $\{y_n\}$.

Comment: I think there must be a little correction (don't take $\,\{x_n\}\,$ but a subsequence of it that converges to some $\;x\in [a,b]\;$), but imo Paul's answer's basically correct. and the downvote seems too harsh.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I cannot agree with you. How could you find $x_0$, such that $x_n$ is convergent? For me, I think the easiest way is to find a fixed point $x_0$, but then Paul's argument will make no sense. Please notice that for an arbitrary $x_0$, the sequence $x_n$ could be very complicated, at least it could be dense in $[a,b]$.

Comment: @Landscape, I think it's the other way around: let $\,\{x_{n_k}:=f\left(x_{n_k-1}\right)\}\,$ be a subsequence of $\;\{x_0, x_1:=f(x_0),x_2:=f(x_1),\ldots\}\;$ converging to some $\;x\in [a,b]\,$ (exists such subseq. by compactness) , and now use continuity of $\,f\,$ to show $\;x\;$ is a fixed point. We do *not* begin with "a fixed point" which existence we **still** have to prove!

Comment: @DonAntonio: Once you have defined $x_n=f(x_{n-1})$ for every $n\ge 1$, you cannot redefine $x_{n_k}:=f(x_{n_{k-1}})$.

Comment: I agree with you, @Landscape, as the indexes could be wild... *though* they **must** be an ascending sequence on the naturals, but still you have the subsequence $\,\{x_{n_1},x_{n_2},...\} =\{f(x_{n_1-1})\,,\,f(x_{n_2-1}),...\}\;$ I'm not saying these indexes are consecutive, and not even the nonsense I wrote in my past comment: they're just indexes...For example, it could be $$\{x_2=f(x_1), x_{11}=f(x_{10}), x_{1334}=f(x_{1333}),...\}$$

Comment: @DonAntonio: However, if you only know that $x_{n_k}$ is convergent, you cannot say anything about whether its limit is a fixed point or not. Here is a simple example to show the absurdity of Paul's argument: $f(x)=1-x$ on $[0,1]$ and $x_0=0$. I didn't want to show such examples because it gives one some illusion that the situation is not too bad. Actually, as I mentioned before, there are many examples of $f$ which are so called [topologically transitive](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Topological_transitivity), for those maps the orbits of many initial points are dense in $[a,b]$.

Comment: I still don't get your point, @Landscape, and even less I understand your example, which has $\,x=0.5\,$ as a fixed point. What I say is $$x_{n_k}\xrightarrow [k\to\infty]{}x\implies \lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})=f(\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k})=f(x)\;\ldots\ldots$$ I can't see a flaw here...

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now...! From $\,f(x_{n_k})=x_{n_k-1}\;$ I can **not** deduce that **also** the subsequence $\,\{x_{n_k-1}\}\,$ converges to the same $\,x\,$ as the subseq. $\,x_{n_k}\,$...nor even that it converges at all! Great (though I still don't get your example above), and thanks a lot,@Landscape

Comment: Many times I do delete the nonsenses I write in comments but this time I will leave all this (1) for me and others to learn a very nice thing, and (2) to teach me (oh, yeah: once again!) to be more careful next time.

Comment: @DonAntonio: There is nothing wrong in the evaluation of your limit, but you cannot conclude $f(x)=x$. In my example, $x_{2n}=0$ and $x_{2n+1}=1$. Then all the limit points of $x_n$ are $0$ and $1$; you cannot get $0.5$.

Comment: @Paul , I'm afraid I've been convinced duly that your argument is wrong.

Comment: Yes, of course @Landscape...in fact, that line with limits in my comment is perfectly correct...but I can't tell anything about the fixed point.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Here is a further comment. Unfortunately, the topological transitivity of a given map is usually not so easy to show, so I didn't mention that before. If you are interested, you may look at $f(x)=4x(1-x)$ on $[0,1]$ for example. If you allow change the domain of $f$ to a circle, say $S^1:=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, then there are simpler examples: it is easy to see that for any irrational number $\alpha$, the map $f:S^1\to S^1$, $f(x)=x+\alpha$ is topologically transitive.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks for your perfect comments. I've learnt a lot. I will take some time to consider the answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Are you Ok if I delete the answer?

Comment: @Landscape: Are you OK if I delete the answer, then your comments will also be deleted?

Comment: I'll be fine if @DonAntonio also agrees. By the way, it seems that users of 10k+ reputations could view deleted answers.

Comment: @Landscape: if downvotes are not too many to the answer, maybe I will keep as long as I can.

Comment: @Paul, it's up to you. As you say, people with enough points can see all deleted questions so it doesn't really matter, yet I think this could really teach some people several nice things. I know I learned something.

Comment: @Paul: If you want to delete, please feel free to do that; if not, you may either edit your answer to indicate that your argument is flawed or replace your argument with a correct one if possible. Thank you for your consideration to ask my opinion. :)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Apply [Intermediate Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) on the function $g(x) = f(x) - x$.

The closed interval is needed, because of the conditions of IVT. For example, the function $f:(0,\infty) \rightarrow ( 0, \infty)$ given by $f(x) = x + 1$ has no fixed point. You can modify this slightly if you want an interval $[a,b)$ or $(a,b)$.

Comment: @P Yup, that was what I was thinking of, without giving it away completely, since this is a very basic question.

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I have an ideal .

1) We have $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ ($f$ is continuous mapping ) has a fixed point . ( from $x-f(x)=g(x)$ with $g(z)=0\Rightarrow z=f(z)$.

2) We need prove that : $X,Y$ be homeomorphic topological spaces. then each continous mapping $h:X\rightarrow X$ has a fixed point if and only if $k:Y\rightarrow Y$ has a fix point .

$Proff.$ 
We have $h:X\rightarrow X$ , $g:Y\rightarrow X$,$f:X\rightarrow Y$ , $k:Y\rightarrow Y$.Suppose $h$ has a fixed point , then $h=g.k.f$ is continuous $z\in X : h(z)=z$. Let $w=f(z)$. We have $k(w)=k(f(z))=fg(k(f(z)))=f(h(z))=f(z)=w.$. Thus $w$ is fixed point of $k$.