# Why are $g(1) < 0, g(0) > 0$ in proof of Fixed-point property for continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Can someone please help me understand how, in the solution below, we can get to $g(1)<0$ and $g(0)>0$ from the fact that $g(1) \neq 0 $  and $ g(0) \neq 0 $?

Thanks.

Rudin Chapter 4, question 14 (Exercise 4.14)

[image: From a solutions webpage]

Comment: Hint: what are the ranges of values that $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ can be?

Comment: where did you get solutions to rudin ?

Comment: I think there is typo. The '$0 \neq f(x) \neq 1$' should be '$0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$'.

Comment: [Continuous function from the unit interval into the unit interval has a fixed point](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512786/continuous-function-from-the-unit-interval-into-the-unit-interval-has-a-fixed-po) and [Show that a continuous function has a fixed point](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13582/show-that-a-continuous-function-has-a-fixed-point)

Comment: @DonAnselmo When I googled for [rudin "suppose f is continuous mapping of I into I"](http://www.google.com/search?q=rudin+%22suppose%20f%20is%20continuous%20mapping%20of%20I%20into%20I%22) 
I found [this file](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/book/Rudin/Rudin_4.pdf). It seems it might be from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that is because f is a map to [0,1]

and therefore f can get a max value of 1 and min value of 0

because we assume that $f(1)\ne1$ it clear that $f(1)<1$
and $f(0)\ne0$ so it clear that $f(0)>0$
and we get

$g(1)= f(1)-1 <1-1 =0$

$g(0) =f(0)-0 =f(0) >0$

have a nice day

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2):

One of the hypothesis is that $f$ maps $I$ onto $I$, this means that for all $x\in I$, it holds that $0\leq f(x)\leq 1$. If $f(1)-1\neq 0$ and $f(0)-0\neq 0$, then $f(1)<1$ and $f(0)>0$, thus $g(1)<0$ and $g(0)>0$.