# For every continuous function $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ there exists $y\in [0,1]$ such that $f(y)=y$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

I want to prove that if we have a continuous function from the closed interval [0,1] to the closed interval [0,1], that there exists a value y in [0,1] such that $f(y)=y$.

I have an idea of a theorem that I want to use:
Let f is a continuous real function on the interval [a,b]. If f(a) < f(b) and if c is a number such that f(a)< c < f(b), then there exists a point x in (a,b) such that f(x)=c.

So I know that f(0) < f(1). So according to this theorem, for some number in between 0 and 1, there exists a point in the domain such that f(x)=this number. 
But I'm having trouble coming up with the argument

Comment: try $g(x) = f(x) - x$, we have $g(0) \ge 0$ and $g(1) \le 1$ because of the range of $f$ is $[0,1]$. That means you can apply the intermediate value theorem here with $g$.

Comment: how did you come up with this function?

Comment: (thank you by the way)

Comment: well you did suggest the use of intermediate value theorem and when we want to prove $f(c) = c$ it's natural to look at how $f(x) - x$ behaves.

Comment: ok,i guess I am not familiar enough with the theorem to see that. Ill think about it some more,thanks!

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate of [Show that a continuous function has a fixed point](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/13582)

Comment: you posted the same thing twice. thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

As @sciona has already pointed out, try using $g(x) = f(x)-x$ and the Intermediate Value Theorem (which you stated). I wanted to add one very subtle point though: The IVT you stated is for points $c$ greater/less than **but not equal** to $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. For example, you couldn't find your desired $y$ for $f(x) = 0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ by just checking points on the open interval $(0,1)$. That means we need to check the end points **separately**, and *then* use the IVT for the points in between.

Comment: Okay thanks.just to make sure I understand; if the intervals were open rather than closed,I wouldn't have to worry about that?

Comment: If your function was $f:[0,1]\to (0,1)$, then yes, that would be correct. You'd have $f(0)>0$ and $f(1)<1$ by the definition of the range, so $g(0)>0$ and $g(1)<0$. The theorem works from there. It's really just the cases $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1)=1$ in your problem that you need to worry about.