# Let f:[0,1]→[0,1] be a continuous function. Show that there exists c ∈[0,1]. Such that f(c)^2 = c.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a continuous function.  Show that there exists a $c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)^2 = c$.

This all the information I have. I am not quite sure of what to do.

Comment: Are you saying $(f(c))^2 = c$ or $f(f(c)) = c$?

Comment: @Joe, it's a function taking values in the closed unit interval.

Comment: There I have fixed it. @Joe

Comment: Hint: consider $g(x) = f(x)^2 - x$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that a continuous function has a fixed point](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13582/show-that-a-continuous-function-has-a-fixed-point)

Comment: @Sally I dont think it is. I wouldn't have created an account for just one question

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $g(x)=x-f(x)^2$ on $[0,1]$ and use the intermediate value theorem to argue that there must be a root. Look at $g(0)$ and $g(1)$, we can assume that $f(0)\neq0$ and $f(1)\neq1$ since otherwise we are done.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider the continuous function $$h:[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}:x\mapsto f(x)^2-x.$$ What can you say about $h(0)$ and $h(1)$? Conclude using the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: The fact that it is the _square_ of a continuous function ($f(c)^2=c$) doesn't bring any "added value" compared to the raw problem ($f(c)=c$)...

Comment: The endpoints of the interval matter. If the end point was 2 instead of 1, then the image could have points getting mapped outside.