# Let $f$ be an continuous function and show that it exists.

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I need some help with this question:

Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a continuous function.  Show that there exists a $c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)^2 = c$.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that a continuous function has a fixed point](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13582/show-that-a-continuous-function-has-a-fixed-point)

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ also $f(x)^2$ is continuous on the same domain since the square function is continuous, so the existence of $c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)^2=c$ is a consequence of the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) for the function $g(x)=f(x)^2-x$. See:  [Show that a continuous function has a fixed point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13582/show-that-a-continuous-function-has-a-fixed-point).

Comment: Where I am wrong?

Comment: I have no idea why you were down voted.  But don't use $g(x) = f(x)^2 -x$ use $g(x) = f(x)^2$.  And, I suppose, you must show that the range of f([0,1]) = g([0,1]) = [0,1].  But otherwise you answer is exactly correct.

Comment: Oh, ... you are using g(x) = f(x)^2 -x to show that g(c) = 0 for some c.  That's good.  But the intermediate value theorem can be assumed to be proven so that isn't necessary.

Comment: Maybe it's not necessary, but it is not wrong. Sometimes the downvotes are  not inetellegible !

Comment: Definitely *NOT* wrong.  I'll upvote to counter it because ... it doesn't make sense that it was downvoted.

Comment: I am not the downvoter but one might downvote this because you provided a full answer to a problem statement question. Many people do this as have I on really egregious occasions.