# Fixed point theorem (At least one fixed point)

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

In fixed point theorem, If g is a continuous function $ g(x) \in [a,b]$ for all $ x \in [a,b]$, then  g has a fixed point in $[a,b]$ i.e. $ c \in [a,b]$ such that $g(c)=c$

According to this theorem, We have exactly one fixed point or at least one fixed point?

Comment: $g$ has at least one fixed point.

Comment: For example take $g(x)=x$, which has many fixed points.

Comment: How to prove this?

Comment: Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that a continuous function has a fixed point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13582/show-that-a-continuous-function-has-a-fixed-point)

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality you can reparametrize $[a,b]$ with $[0,1]$.

Given $g$ define $f(t)=g(t)-t$.

$f$ is continuous. Since $g$ takes value in $[0,1]$, then 
 and $f(0)\geq 0$ and $f(1)\leq 0$. By the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), there is **at least one** $t\in[0,1]$ so that $f(t)=0$, which implies $g(t)=t$.

Comment: Reparametrization is just psicological. Even if you don't reparametrize, if you set $f(t)=g(t)-t$ you have $f(a)\geq 0$ and $f(b)\leq  0$, and the intermediate value theorema apply.