# Let $f:X\to X $ be continuous. Does $f $ have a fixed point when $X=[0,1)$ or $X=(0,1) $?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $f:X\to X $ be continuous. Show that if $X=[0,1] $, $f $ has a
>   fixed point(i.e. there exists  $x$ such that $f (x)=x$). What happens
>   if $X $ equals  $[0,1) $ or $(0,1) $?

First part of the question is an immediate consequence of intermediate value theorem(for a proof, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13585/588038)). I think $f (x)=x^2$ is a counterexample when $X=(0,1) $, since $x^2\lt x $ for all $x\in (0,1) $. But to be honest, I don't *understand* what causes breakdown of the fixed point theorem on $(0,1)$, since IVT only requires connectedness of domain. Is this related to the non-compactness of $(0,1)$?

Also I can't think of any counterexample for the case $X=[0,1)$(assuming fixed point is somehow related to compactness).

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: A circle is compact and connected. But a rotation of it by $180^o$ about its center is a continuous map with no fixed point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The IVT is not the only ingredient here. The way the theorem works is by setting up this square:

[image]

where the line in the middle is $y = x$. A function from $[0, 1]$ to $[0, 1]$ that intersects this line will have a fixed point at the point of intersection.

The IVT kicks in when we have a function whose graph enters the top triangle and the bottom triangle at various points, e.g.

[image]

The fact is, by the IVT, the function has to cut the line somewhere, i.e. it must have a fixed point.

But, this makes an assumption! The function may only exist in one triangle or the other, but not in both. That is, why can we not have $f(x) > x$ for all $x$ or $f(x) < x$ for all $x$?

[image]

The picture above illustrates it. Due to the function having a full domain of $[0, 1]$, there's a squeeze happening. The green function is about as close as we can have to a function satisfying $f(x) > x$. Similarly, the red function attempts to have $f(x) < x$. But, both are pinched towards the diagonal line. The green function must have $f(1) = 1$, and the red function must have $f(0) = 0$.

This illustrates the necessity of defining all the way to $0$ and $1$. Removing either of these points means that the functions are not squeezed to a fixed point (we'd only ensure that $f(x)$ and $x$ become arbitrarily close).

Comment: what about when we define the function on $[0,1]$ but the function is not continuous, I was able to come up with the following example $f(x) = 1/2$ for $x = 0$ and $f(x) = x/2$ otherwise, is this a correct counter example???

Comment: @user601297 Yes, that's a correct counterexample.

Answer (score 4):

The compactness is not really used in proving the FPP for $[0,1]$. We do use both endpoints (we use $f(0) >0$ and $f(1) <1$ when $f$ has no fixpoint in $\{0,1\}$ which then triggers the IVT). You could say that compactness forces these endpoints to be in your set.. (compact and connected in $\mathbb{R}$ means homeomorphic to $[0,1]$).

So to find a counterexample, look for functions on $[0,1]$ with a *unique* fixed point that is either $0$ or $1$. Then removing that point makes a counterexample. $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x$ is an easy one for $X=(0,1]$ e.g.

Answer (score 3):

$$f:[0,1) \to [0,1), x \mapsto  \frac x2 + \frac12$$
$$f:(0,1) \to (0,1), x \mapsto  \frac x2 + \frac12$$
If $x = f(x)$, then $x = 1$ which is not in the domain of $f$.

$$f:(0,1] \to (0,1], x \mapsto \frac x2$$ also has no fixed points.