# Fixed point theorem on disjoint interval

Tags: calculus, fixed-point-theorems

I am to prove that there exists $x^*\in [0,1] \cup [2,3]$ for a function $f$ from $[0,1] \cup [2,3] \to [0,1] \cup [2,3]$ s.t $f(x^*) = x*$ basically the fixed point theorem for the above disjoint interval. It is given that $f$ is continous.

My attempt : I tried going the standard route and define $g(x) = f(x) - x$ then i say that $g(0) > 0$ for $g(1)$ we have two cases it can be either positive or negative, if it is negative then proof is done by IVT, if it is positive then I check $g(2)$ which again has the same two cases, now if $g(2)$ is also positive then I check for $g(3)$ and I say that $g(3)$ has to be negative. 
So now I have $g(0) > 0$ and $g(3) < 0$ so by invoking IVT I could say that there exists a point s.t. $f(x^*) = x^*$ but since the interval is disjoint I am not sure that I can use IVT here( or maybe the function being continuous allows me to???).

So can someone help me out in this and let me know if there is a proof for the above problem if my proof is incorrect.

Comment: IVT stands for?

Comment: The fixed point theorem doesn't hold on sets such as these. Start looking for a counterexample.

Comment: @mvw intermediate value theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim in the question is not true in general: let $f(x)=3-x$ for $x$ in its domain, then an $x^*$ does not exist.

Comment: Ok thanks, so it can be both true and false depending on the scenario

Comment: @user601297 Or rather, sometimes true sometimes false.

Comment: what can we say about the fixed point theorem on $(0,1)$ where $f$ is continuous and what about on [0,1] but $f$ is discontinuous???

Comment: @user601297 Please ask that in another question, and upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: @user601297 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3114789/let-fx-to-x-be-continuous-does-f-have-a-fixed-point-when-x-0-1-or-x/3114810#3114810