# There exists a continuous function $f$ such that $f(\Bbb Q) \subseteq \Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ and $f(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)\subseteq\Bbb Q$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, functions, continuity

True or false: There exists a continuous function  $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that $f(\Bbb Q) \subseteq {\Bbb R}\setminus {\Bbb Q}$ and $f({\Bbb R}\setminus {\Bbb Q}) \subseteq {\Bbb Q}$.

My attempt: I was trying to use the sequential definition of continuity. Consider $a \in \Bbb R$ then we have a seqn ${x_n}$ of rational numbers converging to $a$ and we have a seqn ${y_n}$ of irrational numbers converging to $a$. Then what will be $f(a)$? 
I was thinking that in one way $f(a) \in \Bbb Q$ and on the other way $ f(a) \in {\Bbb R}\setminus {\Bbb Q}$ . But I am wrong $\{f(x_n)\} \subseteq {\Bbb R}\setminus {\Bbb Q}$ and $\{f(y_n)\} \subseteq {\Bbb Q}$ still $f(a)$ can be anywhere.

Is there any way to fix my attempt or any other possible idea?

Comment: Hint: suppose $f$ is nonconstant, and let $a,b$ be two of its values. Then $f$ should take uncountably many irrational values between $a,b$.

Comment: @Wojowu In fact you don't have to suppose $f$ is nonconstant, it is a consequence of the assumptions.

Comment: @TonyS.F. My argument would require considering two cases, constant vs nonconstant. The former is immediate though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a nice proof of this fact, which doesn't use cardinality. Assume such $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ exists. You can do two modifications to $f$ which wont change the property that $f(\Bbb Q) \subseteq {\Bbb R}\setminus {\Bbb Q}$ and $f({\Bbb R}\setminus {\Bbb Q}) \subseteq {\Bbb Q}$:

- You can add a rationnal number to $f$, i.e take $\tilde{f}$ defined by $\tilde{f}(x)=f(x)+p/q$.
- You can multiply $f$ by a rational number, i.e take $\tilde{f}$ defined by $\tilde{f}(x)=(p/q)\times f(x)$.

Now define $g=f\vert_{[0,1]}$.  Then $g$ is continuous and bounded. By adding a "big" rational number to $f$ you can assume $g\geq 0$. By multiplying $f$ by a "small" positive rational number you can also assume $g\leq 1$. Finally you have found $g:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ which is continuous and send rational numbers to irrational and conversely. But this is not possible, as $g$ must have a fixed point.

Comment: You said “$g$ is continuous and bounded”. What’s $g$?

Comment: @Lubin It was not at the right place I edited my answer

Comment: Why does $g$ have a fixed point? Is it immediate?

Comment: @Hunter It's a "classical result", just apply the intermediate value theorem to the continuous function $x\mapsto g(x)-x$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13582/show-that-a-continuous-function-has-a-fixed-point).